# Logging in Python Django: INFO not logging onto file

Tags: python, django, logging

I have setup a logger in my Django project for 4 different cases: info messages, debug messages, error messages, ad gunicorn logging.

Here is the content of my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "main_formatter": {
            "format": "{asctime}-{levelname}-{module}-{funcName}-{message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "main_formatter",
        },
        "dfile": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/debug.log",
            "formatter": "main_formatter",
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/info.log",
            "formatter": "main_formatter",
        },
        "efile": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/error.log",
            "formatter": "main_formatter",
        },
        "gfile": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/gunicorn.log",
            "formatter": "main_formatter",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "main": {
            "handlers": ["dfile", "console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "main": {
            "handlers": ["file", "console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "level": "INFO",
        },
        "main": {
            "handlers": ["efile", "console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "level": "ERROR",
        },
        "gunicorn.access": {
            "handlers": ["gfile", "console"],
            "propagate": False,
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    },
}
```

And here is an example:

```
import logging
[...]
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
[...]
logger.error(f"{request.user}: Erreur interne. Code [LI.001]") # THIS WORKS
logger.info(f"Password Generated and Sent to {email}") # THIS DOESNT WORK
```

In my logs/ folder, I have 4 files: `info.log`, `error.log`, `debug.log` and `gunicorn.log`

The only output I see is in `error.log` and `gunicorn.log`, the other 2 files are always empty.

Comment: If you create multiple items with the same key in a dictionary, one will overwrite the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Django's logging.  But it sticks out to me that your `loggers` dictionary appears to specify the `main` key 3 times.  I would expect that each one overwrites the previous and so your DEBUG and INFO settings are being lost/replaced with your ERROR settings.

Comment: Ok and how can I log all the cases into specific files? I want to have an error file to check the errors, while keeping the normal events in an info.log file so I can refer back to them whenever I need to know if an action has been taken or not. Of course the ideal is to run an ELK stack but the project is still starting.